Discord Js V14 Setting permissions on channel not working as expected
when creating a channel with the bot i wanted originally to set the permissions for everyone to not see the channel but for a specific role to see it and for the person that used the command to see the channel
        const everyone = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "@everyone");

        const channelName = `ticket-${i}`;

        await interaction.guild.channels.create({
            name: channelName,
            type: 0, // Text channel
            parent: ticketCategory.id,
            permissionOverwrites: [{
                    id: everyone,
                    deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']
                },
                {
                    id: message.author.id,
                    allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL']

                }
            ]
        });

nothing happened ....

According to discordjs guide: The guild ID doubles as the role id for the default role @everyone...
They encourage the use of channel.guild.roles.everyone property
